# Is a Kinect unit tied to one Xbox?

Tags: kinect

I recently bought the Xbox 250GB Kinect bundle, and don't have as much room as I thought I needed to play Kinect effectively. So if I sold the Kinect unit, could it be used on another Xbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the kinect is not tied to any one console. However, the kinect in the console bundle does not have the independent power supply that a user with one of the "older style" consoles would need, so if you want to be responsible you should check that the person buying it from you has one of the slim/quiet/cheap shiny plastic models.

Answer (score 1):

Kinect is a console accessory, so it will be compatible with any xbox (if, for instance, you want to take it over to your friend's house). That said, speak with the folks at the store you bought it from -- you may not be able to return *just* the Kinect if you bought it as part of a bundle.